# Effective construction std::string from std::unordered_set<char>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, unordered-set

I have an unordered_set of chars

```
std::unordered_set<char> u_setAlphabet;
```

Then I want to get a content from the set as std::string. My implementation now looks like this:

```
std::string getAlphabet() {
    std::string strAlphabet;
    for (const char& character : u_setAlphabet)
        strAlphabet += character;
    return strAlphabet;
}
```

Is this a good way to solve this task? The additions of signle chars to string seems not to be optimal for large u_setAlphabet (multiple reallocs?). Is there any other method to it?

Comment: As a matter of etiquette: an identifier in a piece of minimal, representative example code should probably not be unwieldily awkward like `u_setAlphabet`. Good identifiers for example code are `foo`, `bar` and `x`.

Comment: @KerrekSB On the other hand, I must say I prefer code which copies an unordered set `setAlphabet` into a string `strAlphabet` to one which copies set (or was is string?) `foo` into string (or was it set?) `bar`.

Comment: @KerrekSB good point, I have in mind your recommendation at the next question. Some answers using these names now, so I won't change question's content here

Comment: @Angew: Keep it short and to the point. Don't go Hungarian, even in spirit. If the code only contains one set and one string, short names are entirely serviceable, and we can see the types in the declarations. Usually what's of interest is the structure of the code, not so the concrete use case, and it's distracting to have a lot of long and very similar identifiers. The worst culprits are things like `class Class; class Class1; void Class1::myOverridingMethod` etc, which feel like they're crafted with the express purpose of making the reader stumble...

Comment: I think alphabet should be sorted

Comment: And what do you mean by "large" alphabet? 256? I doubt you would notice difference.

Comment: @Slava it's really alphabet of Turing Machine, worth for me is only fast recognize if the alphabet has some sign (and an unordered_set is the fastest for this purpose).
And sure - it won't be large set, but I wanted to find some more proper (and more clear) way to reach this task

Comment: Just a side comment.. since your source is an unordered_set, be aware that the string you end up with will not be in any predictable order.

Comment: I'm aware of this. The getAlphabet() func won't be used very often (and if I would need sorted one - I simply sort it). Otherside - cplusplus.com said unordered_set is much faster than set with accessing data. And it's great for me - checking if some element is in the unordered_set will happen a thousands times :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest, most readable and most efficient answer is:

```
return std:string(s.begin(), s.end());
```

The implementation may choose to detect the length of the range up-front and only allocate once; both libc++ and libstdc++ do this when given a forward iterator range.

The `string` class also offers you `reserve`, just like `vector`, to manage the capacity:

```
std::string result
result.reserve(s.size());
for (unsigned char c : s) result.push_back(c);   // or std::copy
return result;
```

It also offers `assign`, `append` and `insert` member functions, but since those offer the strong exception guarantee, they may have to allocate a new buffer before destroying the old one (thanks to @T.C. for pointing out this crucial detail!). The libc++ implementation does not reallocate if the existing capacity suffices, while GCC5's libstdc++ implementation reallocates unconditionally.

Comment: ouh, reserve, I forgot about it :) But doesn't the std::string constructor optimize this by itself?

Comment: I would recomment the `reserve()` code only if you know that you are really in performance critical code and you have found a difference by measuring it. It uglifies your code, but if the gain justifies it, it's fine. A good standard library implementation will reserve memory only once even with the constructor taking iterators. The only overhead you'll get is the traversal to find the size up front.

Comment: @saleph No, as `std::set<T>::iterator` only satisfies BidirectionalIterator `std::distance` is therefore a O(N) operation. However, `std::set<T>::size` is a constant time operation.

Comment: @Daniel If we are concerned about the traversal cost, then even `reserve`+`assign` won't necessarily help, because implementations may still use `distance` in `assign` to determine whether reallocation is needed up-front.

Comment: In fact, in libstdc++'s implementation, `reserve` + `assign` performs two allocations, while using the range constructor allocates only once.

Comment: @T.C.: Interesting. libc++ does not. Maybe worth a bug report?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think this needs more thinking. `assign` is supposed to have strong exception safety, which libc++'s implementation doesn't have, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @T.C.: Interestingly, the iterator *constructor* is actually the most efficient form on both libc++ and libstdc++! See [demo](https://ideone.com/nLE7A2),

Comment: @T.C.: Ah yes, good point. That means that whether the implementation can measure the size is actually independent of `reserve`. If it does measure, then the constructor is just as good.

Comment: @T.C.: Major rewording; [demo on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VStvVmQ1BI1P4qSE) lets you switch libraries and compilers.

Comment: @Daniel: Even the cost of an O(N) distance is worth avoiding reallocations. It's only for strict input iterators that you cannot compute the size.

Comment: Note that if the data source is in something that supports random access (like `string` or `vector`), then calculating the distance between `begin` and `end` is a constant-time operation, and thus does not require traversing the sequence twice.

Answer (score 12):

`std::string` has [a constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) for that:

```
auto s = std::string(begin(u_setAlphabet), end(u_setAlphabet));
```

Answer (score 10):

It is better to use the constructor that acepts iterators. For example

```
std::string getAlphabet() {
    return { u_setAlphabet.begin(), u_setAlphabet.end() };
}
```

Comment: it's much in c++11 style :) But what are you think (in your opinion) about readability diffrences between your and @xtofl aswer? Right - your implementation is the shortest, but it looks like some kind of magic at the first look :)

Comment: @saleph If C++ looks like a magic for you then you should learn C++:) As for the comparison then 1) the answer of xtofl  is also is written using C++ 11 features and 2) it does not correspond to the question where there is said about a function definition.

Comment: Of course I understand your code :) But isn't your implementation very similar to @KerrecSB one? He constructs a string, which will be surely only moved later (eg. `std::string foo ( getAlphabet() );`)

Comment: @saleph The answer of KerrecSB  appeared after my answer. And I consider that my solution is better. There is no any need to specify std::string in the return statement because the function is already declared as having return type std::string.

Comment: hmm, but your code before return produce a list of chars, right? So, when do a string appear? It's some kind of hide-construction?

Comment: @saleph No, it doesn't create a list of chars. It uses list-initialisation to initialise the return value. Initialising a `std::string` with list initialisation using a pair of iterators results in calling the two-iterator constructor.

Comment: ok, so does @VladfromMoscow code have the same result (and do the same) as `return std::string { u_setAlphabet.begin(), u_setAlphabet.end() };`?

Answer (score 1):

Both `return std::string(u_setAlphabet.begin(), u_setAlphabet.end());` and `return { u_setAlphabet.begin(), u_setAlphabet.end();` are the same in C++11. I prefer @VladfromMoscow solution because we do not need to make any assumption about the returned type of the temporary object.

Comment: but isn't this hidden-construction less clear in your opinion? I'm really begginer in c++, so my readability sense isn't very experienced :)